# Does Dart support enumerations?

Tags: enums, dart

Does Dart support enumerations? For instance:

```
enum myFruitEnum { Apple, Banana }
```

A cursory search of the docs suggests no.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=88 - it appears not

Comment: yes. Dart supports Enums

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Beginning [1.8](http://news.dartlang.org/2014/11/dart-18-library-improvements-and.html), you can use enums like this:

```dart
enum Fruit {
  apple, banana
}

main() {
  var a = Fruit.apple;
  switch (a) {
    case Fruit.apple:
      print('it is an apple');
      break;
  }

  // get all the values of the enums
  for (List<Fruit> value in Fruit.values) {
    print(value);
  }

  // get the second value
  print(Fruit.values[1]);
}
```

---

The old approach before 1.8:

```dart
class Fruit {
  static const APPLE = const Fruit._(0);
  static const BANANA = const Fruit._(1);

  static get values => [APPLE, BANANA];

  final int value;

  const Fruit._(this.value);
}
```

Those static constants within the class are compile time constants, and this class can now be used in, for example, `switch` statements:

```dart
var a = Fruit.APPLE;
switch (a) {
  case Fruit.APPLE:
    print('Yes!');
    break;
}
```

Comment: Using `const` is not always possible (if the enum is built with attributes that can not be `const`). That's why I didn't use it in my answer (although I sometimes use `const` enum in my code).

Comment: i will be accepting this answer because it certainly will be useful to use the psuedo enum type in a switch statement

Comment: Is there a way to get the String value of the enumerated item? I think static fields will be a better way to go till enums are fully supported if not.

Comment: @BraveNewMath What do you mean by "String value of the enumerated item"? Can you give me an example of what you are trying to achieve with this string?

Comment: for example, I want to extract the word Apple from the innumeration.  see http://stackoverflow.com/a/13914679/551811 .  I think using this approach is less verbose and more intuitive

Comment: @KaiSellgren Note I think the style guide has now changed, so the enum values should be lower camel case instead of all caps. See https://www.dartlang.org/articles/style-guide/#prefer-using-lowercamelcase-for-constant-names

Comment: Do you know how to use the experimental enums in 1.8? When I try `pub serve` I get `Experimental language feature 'enums' is not supported.
Use option '--enable-enum' to use enum declarations.` Adding that is not a valid option and I couldn't find documentation anywhere... Thx. PS: I am not using the 'official' Dart Editor.

Comment: What's`List<Fruit> value`?

Comment: You probably meant to write `for (Fruit value in Fruit.values)`, otherwise Dart shows an error

Answer (score 9):

With r41815 Dart got native Enum support see http://dartbug.com/21416 and can be used like

```dart
enum Status {
  none,
  running,
  stopped,
  paused
}

void main() {
  print(Status.values);
  Status.values.forEach((v) => print('value: $v, index: ${v.index}'));
  print('running: ${Status.running}, ${Status.running.index}');
  print('running index: ${Status.values[1]}');
}
```

> [Status.none, Status.running, Status.stopped, Status.paused]
>   value: Status.none, index: 0
>   value: Status.running, index: 1
>   value: Status.stopped, index: 2
>   value: Status.paused, index: 3
>   running: Status.running, 1
>   running index: Status.running

A limitation is that it is not possibly to set custom values for an enum item, they are automatically numbered.

More details at in this draft https://www.dartlang.org/docs/spec/EnumsTC52draft.pdf

Comment: User Enum with extensions it will solve all the problems https://arkapp.medium.com/supercharge-enum-with-extensions-in-flutter-abf8fdf706fe

Answer (score 5):

Enumeration should be available in the future. But until [Enum has landed](http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=88) you can do something like :

```dart
class Fruit {
  static final APPLE = new Fruit._();
  static final BANANA = new Fruit._();

  static get values => [APPLE, BANANA];

  Fruit._();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[This](http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=88) and [this](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!msg/misc/GkGw4Ewni6o/BoouMFKo-YEJ) may be the answers on your question:

```
... for the technology preview it was decided to leave it out and just 
use static final fields for now. It may be added later.
```

You can still do something like this:

```
interface ConnectionState { }
class Connected implements ConnectionState { }
class Connecting implements ConnectionState { }
class Disconnected implements ConnectionState { }

//later
ConnectionState connectionState;
if (connectionState is Connecting) { ... }
```

wich is in my opinion more clear for use. It's a bit more difficult for programming the application structure, but in some cases, it's better and clear.

Comment: I think for this example, it would be better to leave out the interface and use a class.  Interface is an optional abstraction and

Answer (score 2):

how about this approach:

```dart
class FruitEnums {
  static const String Apple = "Apple";
  static const String Banana = "Banana";
}

class EnumUsageExample {

  void DoSomething(){

    var fruit = FruitEnums.Apple;
    String message;
    switch(fruit){
      case(FruitEnums.Apple):
        message = "Now slicing $fruit.";
        break;
      default:
        message = "Now slicing $fruit via default case.";
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't do it like this myself. I would keep the name in uppercase as `Fruit.APPLE`. Then if I wanted textual output, I would have a map that translates them or some language support separately if I wanted to support other languages as well. I also think `switch` statements work best on integers, because then they can be compiled down to a jump table.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Its actually very useful to do Enums in Dart:

```
  enum fruits{
    banana, apple, orange
  }
```

Edited by Pete Alvin's comment!

Comment: Lowercase values are standard.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Types Class File.

[Dart-Types](https://github.com/NabilNoN/dart-types.git)

easy, fast, more powerful and more helpful.

***little problem,** it is this class limited to five Different Choice and plus one for acts as null.*

Answer (score 0):

In case of anybody still searching for a quick solution for this.

We sometimes need integer value for an enum , sometimes string value. So we implement a quick package for this.
[Enum Value Generator](https://pub.dev/packages/mobkit_generator) and an extension to easly generate necessary codes but this is not mandatory.[vscode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bis-cozum.biscozum).
It is also capable of use with jsonAnnotation too.

```
import 'package:mobkit_generator/annotations.dart';

part 'example.g.dart'

@EnumSerializable(String)
enum PersonStr {
  @EnumValue('John')
  name,
  @EnumValue('66')
  number,
}

@EnumSerializable(int)
enum PersonInt {
  @EnumValue(1)
  name,
  @EnumValue('66')
  number,
}
```