# print address of object

Tags: dart

Is there any trick to print the address of a dart object?
I'm having an issue in which I have a standard enum class as described in [Does Dart support enumerations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13899928/does-dart-support-enumerations).

```dart
class Access {
  static const IA = const Access._(0);
  static const RO = const Access._(1);
  static const RW = const Access._(2);
  final int value;
  const Access._(this.value);
...
}
```

The variable *access* is of type Access and the value is 1, yet *access==Access.RO* is returning false.

```dart
var access = _.access;
print('''
access => ($access, ${access.runtimeType}, ${access.value})
static => (${Access.RO}, ${Access.RO.runtimeType}, ${Access.RO.value})
equal ? => ${(access == Access.RO)}
''');
```

prints

```dart
access => (RO, Access, 1)
static => (RO, Access, 1)
equal ? => false
```

If I provide an *operator==(Access other)* that compares the values it returns the expected value. So, I figured maybe this has to do with coming at the class from different libraries (maybe isolate related) and if I could print the address of *access* and *Access.RO* I could see if they are different. Of course, if they were different I'd then need to know why as well.

Answer (score 2):

When you deal with *const* you have to be very careful. If you use `new Access._(0)` instead of `const Access._(0)` you will not get the same object. Here is an example :

```dart
class Access {
  static const IA = const Access._(0);
  static const RO = const Access._(1);
  static const RW = const Access._(2);
  final int value;
  const Access._(this.value);
}

main(){
  print(Access.IA == const Access._(0));  // prints true
  print(Access.IA == new Access._(0));  // prints false
}
```

This could explain your problem.

Comment: Good point - but not the issue, since I do not 'new' them. (In fact - disabling new would be nice). Turns out the app used a library by importing the dart file directly. The library was also pulled in using import package: syntax. They resolved to same file but came in twice. The very nice --print_classes option made it clear. A feature request for dart might be determine uniqueness of library by full location of file pulled in. So, in both scenarios the print address of instance function would shed light. Can it be done?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know if it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

If `identical(a, b)` returns false you can be sure that their pointers are different. (The inverse is not necessarily true for numbers, but that's an implementation detail).

If you are dealing with isolates you need to be careful when you transmit objects. Even, if they are canonicalized on one side, they won't be, after they have been transmitted to another isolate:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:isolate';

class A { const A(); }

foo() {
  port.receive((x, _) {
    print(x == const A());  // Prints false.
  });
}

main() {
  var p = new ReceivePort();  // To keep the program running.
  spawnFunction(foo).send(const A(), null);
}
```

Also note that dart2js doesn't allow to transmit arbitrary objects.

Comment: Given that, with the enum idiom, it probably makes sense to provide an operator== that checks the actual value, rather than rely on oject.operator==? In this case that would be safer. But then, that would not help in situations where the named constant enum value were used in a switch statement?

Comment: I wouldn't overwrite the '==' operator. If you only have a limited set of instances you actually want an identity comparison (which is probably faster too).