# Enum from String

Tags: dart

I have an `Enum` and a function to create it from a `String` because i couldn't find a built in way to do it

```dart
enum Visibility{VISIBLE,COLLAPSED,HIDDEN}

Visibility visibilityFromString(String value){
  return Visibility.values.firstWhere((e)=>
      e.toString().split('.')[1].toUpperCase()==value.toUpperCase());
}

//used as
Visibility x = visibilityFromString('COLLAPSED');
```

but it seems like i have to rewrite this function for every Enum i have, is there a way to write the same function where it takes the Enum type as parameter? i tried to but i figured out that i can't cast to Enum.

```dart
//is something with the following signiture actually possible?
     dynamic enumFromString(Type enumType,String value){

     }
```

Comment: Yeah, there doesn't seem to be a good way to do this. I had looked forward to this feature's inclusion in Dart until I saw how they implemented it. Now, I usually can't justify its use.

Comment: @montyr75 figured, hopefully it will change soon

Comment: It's better to use old-style enums http://stackoverflow.com/a/13901969/217408 if you need something like that

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using mirrors you could force some behaviour. I had two ideas in mind. Unfortunately Dart does not support typed functions:

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';

enum Visibility {VISIBLE, COLLAPSED, HIDDEN}

class EnumFromString<T> {
  T get(String value) {
    return (reflectType(T) as ClassMirror).getField(#values).reflectee.firstWhere((e)=>e.toString().split('.')[1].toUpperCase()==value.toUpperCase());
  }
}

dynamic enumFromString(String value, t) {
  return (reflectType(t) as ClassMirror).getField(#values).reflectee.firstWhere((e)=>e.toString().split('.')[1].toUpperCase()==value.toUpperCase());
}

void main() {
  var converter = new EnumFromString<Visibility>();

  Visibility x = converter.get('COLLAPSED');
  print(x);

  Visibility y = enumFromString('HIDDEN', Visibility);
  print(y);
}
```

Outputs:

```dart
Visibility.COLLAPSED
Visibility.HIDDEN
```

Comment: This code needs a review, It doesnt seem to work in current version

Comment: You can type functions in dart imTyped(String Function(String a, int b) generatedString){
  String newString = generatedString("hello", 5);
  return newString;
}

Comment: Since Dart 2.15 you can use `YourEnum.values.byName("");`.

Answer (score 287):

Mirrors aren't always available, but fortunately you don't need them. This is reasonably compact and should do what you want.

```
enum Fruit { apple, banana }

// Convert to string
String str = Fruit.banana.toString();

// Convert to enum
Fruit f = Fruit.values.firstWhere((e) => e.toString() == 'Fruit.' + str);

assert(f == Fruit.banana);  // it worked
```

Thanks to @frostymarvelous for correcting the answer

Comment: caveat! your string must be in the form of `"Fruit.banana"` to work

Comment: you can also use: `describeEnum`which is in the `package:flutter/foundation.dart` package to get rid of `Fruit.`.

`String str = "banana";
Fruit f = Fruit.values.firstWhere((e) => describeEnum(e) == str);`

Comment: With Dart seemingly doing most things right in it's design, I'm surprised to/from String conversion isn't more elegant; perhaps in the future they will introduce some syntactic sugar for this?

Comment: Simple and to the point answer. I used your code without the fix and it worked perfectly. Thanks

Comment: to cover for unexpected string values: `firstWhere((e) => e.toString() == 'Fruit.' + str, orElse: () => null);`

Comment: @JannieTheunissen if I user this with null safety it doesn't work because a Fruit type is expected

Comment: Since Dart 2.15, we can now access the enum values name as strings (ie: `Fruit.apple.name == 'apple'`) and write: `Fruit f = Fruit.values.firstWhere((e) => e.name == str);` instead of `Fruit f = Fruit.values.firstWhere((e) => e.toString() == 'Fruit.' + str);`

Comment: You can also write `Fruit f = Fruit.values.byName(str)`

Answer (score 133):

As from Dart version 2.15, you can lookup an enum value by name a lot more conveniently, using `.values.byName` or using `.values.asNameMap()`:

```dart
enum Visibility {
  visible, collapsed, hidden
}

void main() {
  // Both calls output `true`
  print(Visibility.values.byName('visible') == Visibility.visible);
  print(Visibility.values.asNameMap()['visible'] == Visibility.visible);
}
```

You can read more about other enum improvements in the official Dart 2.15 announcement [blog post](https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-2-15-7e7a598e508a).

Comment: Considering the new version of Dart this should be now the correct answer.

Comment: Note that `byName` and `asNameMap` are always in O(n) but if you only want to lookup a single enum entry by name it can be faster to use `firstWhere` which is only in its worst case in O(n).

Comment: @Stuck `byName` uses a for loop under the hood so there's no practical difference between that and `firstWhere` apart from readability. But even ignoring that, the enum map would have to be massive for it to make more than a negligible difference. If it's really a concern, cache the value of `asNameMap` and then use that for all future lookups so that it's always O(1).

Comment: Now if there were only ways to convert from object to map in other contexts -- like when doing JSON serialization....

Answer (score 61):

#### Update:

```dart
void main() {
  Day monday = Day.values.byName('monday'); // This is all you need
}

enum Day {
  monday,
  tuesday,
}
```

---

#### Old solution:

Your enum

```
enum Day {
  monday,
  tuesday,
}
```

Add this extension (need a  `import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';`)

```
extension EnumEx on String {
  Day toEnum() => Day.values.firstWhere((d) => describeEnum(d) == toLowerCase());
}
```

Usage:

```
void main() {
  String s = 'monday'; // String
  Day monday = s.toEnum(); // Converted to enum
}
```

Comment: That converts the enum to string. Is it able to convert a string to enum? The question is about that.

Comment: `byName` is the nicest solution by far.

Comment: `byName` is good but throws an errof if no match found

Answer (score 47):

My solution is identical to Rob C's solution but without string interpolation:

```
T enumFromString<T>(Iterable<T> values, String value) {
  return values.firstWhere((type) => type.toString().split(".").last == value,
      orElse: () => null);
}
```

---

Null safe example using `firstWhereOrNull()` from the [collection package](https://pub.dev/packages/collection)

```dart
static T? enumFromString<T>(Iterable<T> values, String value) {
  return values.firstWhereOrNull((type) => type.toString().split(".").last == value);
}
```

Answer (score 31):

This is all so complicated I made a simple library that gets the job done:

https://pub.dev/packages/enum_to_string

```dart
import 'package:enum_to_string:enum_to_string.dart';

enum TestEnum { testValue1 };

convert(){
    String result = EnumToString.parse(TestEnum.testValue1);
    //result = 'testValue1'

    String resultCamelCase = EnumToString.parseCamelCase(TestEnum.testValue1);
    //result = 'Test Value 1'
    
    final result = EnumToString.fromString(TestEnum.values, "testValue1");
    // TestEnum.testValue1
}
```

**Update: 2022/02/10**
Dart v2.15 has implemented some additional enum methods that may solve your problems.

From here: https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-2-15-7e7a598e508a

Improved enums in the dart:core library

We’ve made a number of convenience additions to the enum APIs in the dart:core library (language issue #1511). You can now get the String value for each enum value using .name:

```
enum MyEnum {
  one, two, three
}
void main() {
  print(MyEnum.one.name);  // Prints "one".
}
```

You can also look up an enum value by name:

```
print(MyEnum.values.byName('two') == MyEnum.two);  // Prints "true".
```

Finally, you can get a map of all name-value pairs:

```
final map = MyEnum.values.asNameMap(); 
print(map['three'] == MyEnum.three);  // Prints "true".
```

Comment: Thanks.... MyEnum.values.byName('two') is what I was looking for sometime now..

Comment: this looks like the correct answer now.

Answer (score 16):

Since Dart 2.17 you can solve this elegantly with Enhanced Enums.

(see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71412047/15760132 )

Just add a static method to your enum of choice, like this:

```
enum Example {
  example1,
  example2,
  example3;

  static Example? fromName(String name) {
    for (Example enumVariant in Example.values) {
      if (enumVariant.name == name) return enumVariant;
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Then you can look for the enum like this:

```
Example? test = Example.fromName("example1");
    
print(test);    // returns Example.example1
```

EDIT:

Another user has posted a better solution, which requires no adding of static methods.

Just use the built-in methods, like this:

```
Example? test2 = Example.values.asNameMap()["example1"];

print(test2);    // returns Example.example1
```

Answer (score 11):

[Collin Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1463116/collin-jackson)'s solution didn't work for me because Dart stringifies enums into `EnumName.value` rather than just `value` (for instance, `Fruit.apple`), and I was trying to convert the string value like `apple` rather than converting `Fruit.apple` from the get-go.

With that in mind, this is my solution for the enum from string problem

```
enum Fruit {apple, banana}

Fruit getFruitFromString(String fruit) {
  fruit = 'Fruit.$fruit';
  return Fruit.values.firstWhere((f)=> f.toString() == fruit, orElse: () => null);
}
```

Comment: @Collin Jackson solutions works if you use enum `toString()` to convert enum to string. `toString()` returns 'Fruit.apple'

Comment: To return just "apple", try the following:
Fruit.apple.toString().split(".")[1];

Answer (score 11):

With [Dart 2.15](https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-2-15-7e7a598e508a#:%7E:text=You%20can%20now%20get%20the%20String%20value%20for%20each%20enum%20value%20using%20.name) we can now do this which is much cleaner

```dart
  // Convert to string
  String fruitName = Fruit.banana.name;

  // Convert back to enum
  Fruit fruit = Fruit.values.byName(fruitName);
  print(fruit); // Fruit.banana
  assert(fruit == Fruit.banana);
```

Answer (score 10):

Here is an alternative way to @mbartn's approach using extensions, extending the `enum` itself instead of `String`.

**Faster, but more tedious**

```dart
// We're adding a 'from' entry just to avoid having to use Fruit.apple['banana'],
// which looks confusing.
enum Fruit { from, apple, banana }

extension FruitIndex on Fruit {
  // Overload the [] getter to get the name of the fruit.
  operator[](String key) => (name){
    switch(name) {
      case 'banana': return Fruit.banana;
      case 'apple':  return Fruit.apple;
      default:       throw RangeError("enum Fruit contains no value '$name'");
    }
  }(key);
}

void main() {
  Fruit f = Fruit.from["banana"];
  print("$f is ${f.runtimeType}"); // Outputs: Fruit.banana is Fruit
}
```

**Less tedius, but slower**

If O(n) performance is acceptable you could also incorporate @Collin Jackson's answer:

```dart
// We're adding a 'from' entry just to avoid having to use Fruit.apple['banana']
// which looks confusing.
enum Fruit { from, apple, banana }

extension FruitIndex on Fruit {
  // Overload the [] getter to get the name of the fruit.
  operator[](String key) =>
    Fruit.values.firstWhere((e) => e.toString() == 'Fruit.' + key);
}

void main() {
  Fruit f = Fruit.from["banana"];
  print("$f is ${f.runtimeType}"); // Outputs: Fruit.banana is Fruit
}
```

Comment: Fruit.from["banana"] -> where is this coming from? `from` does not get recognized.

Comment: @uzu `from` is an entry added to the enum to make it less confusing to read the code. You do not have to add it, but then you have to use another existing key instead. For example, if you choose to use `apple`, it would be: `Fruit.apple['banana']`.

Comment: I like your solution, but to make clear `from` is not really a useable enum it might be a good idea to make it private by using `_from` instead. (That limits its use to this file/class, but in many cases this is exactly what you want)

Answer (score 9):

I use this function, I think it's simple and doesn't need any kind of 'hack':

```
T enumFromString<T>(List<T> values, String value) {
    return values.firstWhere((v) => v.toString().split('.')[1] == value,
                             orElse: () => null);
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
enum Test {
    value1,
    value2,
}

var test = enumFromString(Test.value, 'value2') // Test.value2
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Clean, elegant and does not use reflection

Answer (score 8):

In the latest version of Dart, `enum` can support custom fields and methods. So the most modern way to do this, is to write a custom field for name/label, and a static parser function.

For example:

```
enum Foo {
  a('FIRST'),
  b('SECOND'),
  c('THIRD'),
  unknown('UNKNOWN'); // make sure the last element ends in `;`

  final String label; // define a private field

  const Foo(this.label); // constructor

  static Foo fromString(String label) { // static parser method
    return values.firstWhere(
      (v) => v.label == label,
      orElse: () => Foo.unknown,
    );
  }
}
```

Sample Usage:

```
final foo = Foo.fromString('FIRST'); // will get `Foo.a`
```

Answer (score 5):

You can write `getEnum` like below, `getEnum` will go through enum values and returns the first enum that is equal to the desired string.

```dart
Sample getEnum(String name) => Sample.values.firstWhere(
      (v) => v.name.toLowerCase() == name.toLowerCase(),
      orElse: () => throw Exception('Enum value not found.'),
    );

enum SampleEnum { first, second, third }
```

**UPDATE**

also, you can use this:

```dart
final SampleEnum nameEnum = SampleEnum.values.byName('second');  // SampleEnum.second
```

Usage:

```dart
void main() {
  print(getEnum('first'));
}
```

Comment: Plus 1 for byName. I like to stick to language specific construct

Answer (score 4):

I improved [Collin Jackson's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1463116/collin-jackson) answer using Dart 2.7 [Extension Methods](https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods) to make it more elegant.

```
enum Fruit { apple, banana }

extension EnumParser on String {
  Fruit toFruit() {
    return Fruit.values.firstWhere(
        (e) => e.toString().toLowerCase() == 'fruit.$this'.toLowerCase(),
        orElse: () => null); //return null if not found
  }
}

main() {
  Fruit apple = 'apple'.toFruit();
  assert(apple == Fruit.apple); //true
}
```

Comment: It's a good idea to use extension methods for an operation that is often needed when dealing with Enums, however, it doesn't seem like the best idea to make it specific for Fruit. I'd suggest renaming the "toFruit" method to "toEnum" and pass the Enum as an argument to that method instead.

Answer (score 4):

Simplified version:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

static Fruit? valueOf(String value) {
    return Fruit.values.where((e) => describeEnum(e) == value).first;
}
```

Using the method `describeEnum` helps you to avoid the usage of the split to get the name of the element.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with building objects from JSON. In JSON values are strings, but I wanted enum to validate if the value is correct. I wrote this helper which works with any enum, not a specified one:

```
class _EnumHelper {


 var cache = {};

  dynamic str2enum(e, s) {
    var o = {};
    if (!cache.containsKey(e)){
      for (dynamic i in e) {
        o[i.toString().split(".").last] = i;
      }
      cache[e] = o;
    } else {
      o = cache[e];
    }
    return o[s];
  }
}

_EnumHelper enumHelper = _EnumHelper();
```

Usage:

```
enumHelper.str2enum(Category.values, json['category']);
```

PS. I did not use types on purpose here. **enum** is not type in Dart and treating it as one makes things complicated. Class is used solely for caching purposes.

Answer (score 3):

Generalising @CopsOnRoad's solution to work for any enum type,

```
enum Language { en, ar }

extension StringExtension on String {
   T toEnum<T>(List<T> list) => list.firstWhere((d) => d.toString() == this);
}

String langCode = Language.en.toString();
langCode.toEnum(Language.values);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of enums packages which allowed me to get just the enum string rather than the type.value string (Apple, not Fruit.Apple).

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/built_value (this is more up to date)

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/enums

```
void main() {
  print(MyEnum.nr1.index);            // prints 0
  print(MyEnum.nr1.toString());       // prints nr1
  print(MyEnum.valueOf("nr1").index); // prints 0
  print(MyEnum.values[1].toString())  // prints nr2
  print(MyEnum.values.last.index)     // prints 2
  print(MyEnum.values.last.myValue);  // prints 15
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the function that converts given string to enum type:

```
EnumType enumTypeFromString(String typeString) => EnumType.values
    .firstWhere((type) => type.toString() == "EnumType." + typeString);
```

And here is how you convert given enum type to string:

```
String enumTypeToString(EnumType type) => type.toString().split(".")[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

Generalizing on @Pedro Sousa's excellent solution, and using the built-in `describeEnum` function:

```
extension StringExtension on String {
  T toEnum<T extends Object>(List<T> values) {
    return values.singleWhere((v) => this.equalsIgnoreCase(describeEnum(v)));
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
enum TestEnum { none, test1, test2 }
final testEnum = "test1".toEnum(TestEnum.values);
expect(testEnum, TestEnum.test1);
```

Answer (score 2):

```dart
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

enum Page {
  login,
  profile,
  contact,
}

Widget page(String key){
  Page? link = Page.values.firstWhereOrNull((e) => e.toString().split('.').last == key);
  switch (link) {
    case Page.login:
      return LoginView();
    case Page.profile:
      return const ProfileView();
    case Page.contact:
      return const ContactView();
    default:
      return const Empty();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Collin Jackson has a very good answer IMO. I had used a for-in loop to achieve a similar result prior to finding this question. I am definitely switching to using the firstWhere method.

Expanding on his answer this is what I did to deal with removing the type from the value strings:

```
enum Fruit { apple, banana }

class EnumUtil {
    static T fromStringEnum<T>(Iterable<T> values, String stringType) {
        return values.firstWhere(
                (f)=> "${f.toString().substring(f.toString().indexOf('.')+1)}".toString()
                    == stringType, orElse: () => null);
    }
}

main() {
    Fruit result = EnumUtil.fromStringEnum(Fruit.values, "apple");
    assert(result == Fruit.apple);
}
```

Maybe someone will find this useful...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in one of my projects and existing solutions were not very clean and it didn't support advanced features like json serialization/deserialization.

Flutter natively doesn't currently support enum with values, however, I managed to develop a helper package `Vnum` using class and reflectors implementation to overcome this issue.

Address to the repository:

https://github.com/AmirKamali/Flutter_Vnum

To answer your problem using `Vnum`, you could implement your code as below:

```
@VnumDefinition
class Visibility extends Vnum<String> {
  static const VISIBLE = const Visibility.define("VISIBLE");
  static const COLLAPSED = const Visibility.define("COLLAPSED");
  static const HIDDEN = const Visibility.define("HIDDEN");

  const Visibility.define(String fromValue) : super.define(fromValue);
  factory Visibility(String value) => Vnum.fromValue(value,Visibility);
}
```

You can use it like :

```
var visibility = Visibility('COLLAPSED');
print(visibility.value);
```

There's more documentation in the github repo, hope it helps you out.

Answer (score 1):

When migrating to null-safety, the Iterable.firstWhere method no longer accepts orElse: () => null. Here is the implementation considering the null-safety:

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

String enumToString(Object o) => o.toString().split('.').last;

T? enumFromString<T>(String key, List<T> values) => values.firstWhereOrNull((v) => key == enumToString(v!));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
enum Fruit { orange, apple }

// Waiting for Dart static extensions
// Issue https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/723
// So we will be able to Fruit.parse(...)
extension Fruits on Fruit {
  static Fruit? parse(String raw) {
    return Fruit.values
        .firstWhere((v) => v.asString() == raw, orElse: null);
  }

  String asString() {
    return this.toString().split(".").last;
  }
}
...
final fruit = Fruits.parse("orange"); // To enum
final value = fruit.asString(); // To string
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple method which i mostly use:

```
 Gender convertToEnum(String value) {
    if (value.toLowerCase() == "male") {
      return Gender.Male;
    } else if (value.toLowerCase() == "female") {
      return Gender.Female;
    } else {
      return Gender.Others;
    }
  }
```

Call method like this:

```
Gender genderValue = convertToEnum("male");
```

My Enum:

```
Gender{
Male,
Female,
Others
}
```

Comment: This should be avoided as there is a dedicated call to Gender.values.byName(..) which achieves this exact solution with less verbosity.

Answer (score 1):

For O(1) speed (to not iterate values every time, especially for big enum) you may use Map to map String to Enum like this:

```
enum TypedMessageTypes {
  unknown,
  chat,
  common,
  spyChanged,
  ;

  static final map = <String, TypedMessageTypes>{};

  TypedMessageTypes toEnum(String value) {
    if (map.isEmpty) {
      for (final e in TypedMessageTypes.values) {
        map[e.name.toLowerCase()] = e;
      }
    }
    return map[value.toLowerCase()] ?? TypedMessageTypes.unknown;
  }
}
```

And use it like this in code:

```
final enumResult = TypedMessageTypes.toEnum('chat');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think my approach is slightly different, but might be more convenient in some cases. Finally, we have parse and tryParse for enum types:

```
import 'dart:mirrors';

class Enum {
  static T parse<T>(String value) {
    final T result = (reflectType(T) as ClassMirror).getField(#values)
        .reflectee.firstWhere((v)=>v.toString().split('.').last.toLowerCase() == value.toLowerCase()) as T;
    return result;
  }

  static T tryParse<T>(String value, { T defaultValue }) {
    T result = defaultValue;
    try {
      result = parse<T>(value);
    } catch(e){
      print(e);
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

EDIT: this approach is NOT working in the Flutter applications, by default mirrors are blocked in the Flutter because it causes the generated packages to be very large.

Answer (score 0):

enum in Dart just has too many limitations. The extension method could add methods to the instances, but not static methods.

I really wanted to be able to do something like MyType.parse(myString), so eventually resolved to use manually defined classes instead of enums. With some wiring, it is almost functionally equivalent to enum but could be modified more easily.

```
class OrderType {
  final String string;
  const OrderType._(this.string);

  static const delivery = OrderType._('delivery');
  static const pickup = OrderType._('pickup');

  static const values = [delivery, pickup];

  static OrderType parse(String value) {
    switch (value) {
      case 'delivery':
        return OrderType.delivery;
        break;
      case 'pickup':
        return OrderType.pickup;
        break;
      default:
        print('got error, invalid order type $value');
        return null;
    }
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'OrderType.$string';
  }
}

// parse from string
final OrderType type = OrderType.parse('delivery');
assert(type == OrderType.delivery);
assert(type.string == 'delivery');
```

Answer (score 0):

another variant, how it might be solved:

```dart
enum MyEnum {
  value1,
  value2,
}

extension MyEnumX on MyEnum {
  String get asString {
    switch (this) {
      case MyEnum.value1:
        return _keyValue1;
      case MyEnum.value2:
        return _keyValue2;
    }
    throw Exception("unsupported type");
  }

  MyEnum fromString(String string) {
    switch (string) {
      case _keyValue1:
        return MyEnum.value1;
      case _keyValue2:
        return MyEnum.value2;
    }
    throw Exception("unsupported type");
  }
}

const String _keyValue1 = "value1";
const String _keyValue2 = "value2";

void main() {
    String string = MyEnum.value1.asString;
    MyEnum myEnum = MyEnum.value1.fromString(string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    enum HttpMethod { Connect, Delete, Get, Head, Options, Patch, Post, Put, Trace }

    HttpMethod httpMethodFromString({@required String httpMethodName}) {
    assert(httpMethodName != null);

    if (httpMethodName is! String || httpMethodName.isEmpty) {
      return null;
    }

    return HttpMethod.values.firstWhere(
      (e) => e.toString() == httpMethodName,
      orElse: () => null,
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
extension LanguagePreferenceForString on String {
LanguagePreferenceEntity toLanguagePrerence() {
switch (this) {
  case "english":
    return LanguagePreferenceEntity.english;
  case "turkish":
    return LanguagePreferenceEntity.turkish;
  default:
    return LanguagePreferenceEntity.english;
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

enum CalendarType { JALALI, GREGORIAN };
List calendarTypeList = [CalendarType.JALALI.name, CalendarType.GREGORIAN.name];
CalendarType.values.firstWhere((element) => element.name==keyName);

Comment: This answer can use better formatting and a bit of explanation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

This is doable by new `Dart 2.17` feature, called `Enhanced Enum`.

To use this modify dart version to 2.17 and above in `pubspec.yaml`

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.0 <3.0.0"
```

enum Visibility{VISIBLE,COLLAPSED,HIDDEN}

```
enum Visibility{
   VISIBLE("Visible"),
   COLLAPSED("Collapsed"),
   HIDDEN("Hidden");

  const Visibility(this.text);
  final String text;
}
```

***How to use it?***

```
void main() {
  const visibility = Visibility.VISIBLE;
  print(visibility.text); // Visible
}
```

Comment: I think the OP is looking for the opposite behaviour, obtaining an instance of a Visibility from the string representing the name.