# DART - can I cast a string to an enum?

Tags: enums, dart

Is there a way to convert a string to an enum?

```
enum eCommand{fred, joe, harry}

eCommand theCommand= cast(eCommand, 'joe');??
```

I think I just have to search for the enum (eg loop).

cheers

Steve

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enum from String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27673781/enum-from-string)

Answer (score 14):

Dart 2.6 introduces methods on `enum` types. It's much better to call a getter on the `Topic` or `String` itself to get the corresponding conversion via a named extension. I prefer this technique because I don't need to import a new package, saving memory and solving the problem with OOP.

I also get a compiler warning when I update the enum with more cases when I don't use `default`, since I am not handling the switch exhaustively.

Here's an example of that:

```
enum Topic { none, computing, general }

extension TopicString on String {
  Topic get topic {
    switch (this) {
      case 'computing':
        return Topic.computing;
      case 'general':
        return Topic.general;
      case 'none':
        return Topic.none;
    }
  }
}

extension TopicExtension on Topic {
  String get string {
    switch (this) {
      case Topic.computing:
        return 'computing';
      case Topic.general:
        return 'general';
      case Topic.none:
        return 'none';
    }
  }
}
```

This is really easy to use and understand, since I don't create any extra classes for conversion:

```
var topic = Topic.none;
final string = topic.string;
topic = string.topic;
```

(-:

Answer (score 13):

I got annoyed with the state of enums and built a library to handle this:

https://pub.dev/packages/enum_to_string

Basic usage:

```dart
import 'package:enum_to_string:enum_to_string.dart';

enum TestEnum { testValue1 };

main(){
    final result = EnumToString.fromString(TestEnum.values, "testValue1");
    // TestEnum.testValue1
}
```

Still more verbose than I would like, but gets the job done.

Answer (score 9):

I have came up with a solution inspired from https://pub.dev/packages/enum_to_string that can be used as a simple extension on List

```
extension EnumTransform on List {
  String string<T>(T value) {
    if (value == null || (isEmpty)) return null;
    var occurence = singleWhere(
        (enumItem) => enumItem.toString() == value.toString(),
        orElse: () => null);
    if (occurence == null) return null;
    return occurence.toString().split('.').last;
  }

  T enumFromString<T>(String value) {
    return firstWhere((type) => type.toString().split('.').last == value,
        orElse: () => null);
  }
}
```

Usage

```
enum enum Color {
  red,
  green,
  blue,
}

var colorEnum = Color.values.enumFromString('red');
var colorString: Color.values.string(Color.red)
```

Answer (score 6):

As of Dart 2.15, you can use the [name](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.1/dart-core/EnumName/name.html) property and the [byName()](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.1/dart-core/EnumByName/byName.html) method:

```dart
enum eCommand { fred, joe, harry }
eCommand comm = eCommand.fred;

assert(comm.name == "fred");
assert(eCommand.values.byName("fred") == comm);
```

Just be aware that the `byName` method throws an `ArgumentError` if the string is not recognized as a valid member in the enumeration.

Answer (score 3):

For the Dart enum this is a bit cumbersome.

See [Enum from String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27673781/enum-from-string) for a solution.

If you need more than the most basic features of an enum it's usually better to use old-style enums - a class with const members.

See [How can I build an enum with Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15854549/how-can-i-build-an-enum-with-dart) for old-style enums

Comment: 6 years later, is using Freezed to make "data classes" the best way?

Comment: I prefer built_value because it also supports collections (but not unions like freezed does as far as I remember)

Comment: There is currently some work in progress about metaprogramming that should improve this area.

Comment: Having both unions and collections would be superb.

Answer (score 3):

This is the fastest way I found to do this :

```
enum Vegetable { EGGPLANT, CARROT, TOMATO }
Vegetable _getVegetableEnum(dynamic myVegetableObject) {
  return Vegetable.values.firstWhere((e) => describeEnum(e) == myVegetableObject);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem, a small enum and a string, so i did this

```
dynamic _enum_value = EnumFromString(MyEnum.values, string_to_enum);

dynamic EnumFromString(List values, String comp){
  dynamic enumValue = null;
  values.forEach((item) {
    if(item.toString() == comp){
      enumValue =  item;
    }
  });
  return enumValue;
}
```

i know this is not the best solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

[Static extension methods](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/723) would make this nice (currently unimplemented).

Then you could have something like this:

```dart
extension Value on Keyword {
  /// Returns the valid string representation of a [Keyword].
  String value() => toString().replaceFirst(r'Keyword.$', '');

  /// Returns a [Keyword] for a valid string representation, such as "if" or "class".
  static Keyword toEnum(String asString) =>
      Keyword.values.firstWhere((kw) => kw.value() == asString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***FOUND ANS***

- Check this article. Very well explained: [Link](https://prafullkumar77.medium.com/dart-enum-to-string-to-enum-e7fd163a37e3)

  ```
  extension EnumParser on String {
     T toEnum<T>(List<T> values) {
        return values.firstWhere(
             (e) => e.toString().toLowerCase().split(".").last == 
             '$this'.toLowerCase(),
             orElse: () => null,
        ),
     }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way is to use built-in functionality:

```
enum EmailStatus {
  accepted,
  rejected,
  delivered,
  failed,
}
```

`EmailStatus.values.byName('failed') == EmailStatus.failed;`
`=> true`