# How do I add Methods or Values to Enums in Dart?

Tags: dart

In Java when you are defining an enum, you can do something similar to the following, i.e. add members to an `enum`. Is this possible in Dart?

```dart
enum Foo {
  one(1), two(2);
  final num value;
  Foo(this.value);
}
```

Comment: I really don't know why Java / Dart world so resist in the implementation of ``enum``. No ``enum`` is not Class / Const, if there is a need to implement ``enum`` as a Class we can still do so depends on situation. A single line of code in ``enum`` requires > 10 lines of code in all other alternatives. So it is not a syntactic sugar

Answer (score 234, accepted):

## Dart Enhanced Enum Classes

Starting with Dart 2.17, the [Enhanced Enum Classes](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/d16704ae6c9a5fd8f30b7ba9d33a5ab650c7447d/accepted/future-releases/enhanced-enums/feature-specification.md) feature has been introduced. With that, the example from the question would look like this:

```dart
enum Foo {
  one(1),
  two(2);

  const Foo(this.value);
  final num value;
}
```

Now, you can just use the enum class like this:

```dart
void main() {
  const foo = Foo.one;
  print(foo.value); // 1
}
```

Note that you need to update your SDK constraint as the feature requires Dart 2.17:

```yaml
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.17.0-0 <3.0.0'
```

### Adding members

With enhanced enums, you can add **any** member to your enum as long as the **constructor is `const`**.

This also means that you can add getters or methods to existing enums, for example:

```dart
enum Cake {
  cherry,
  apple,
  strawberry;

  String get description => '$name cake';
}
```

### Generics

Enhanced enum classes also enable you to use generics for you enums. If you combine this with members, you can do the following:

```dart
enum Bar<T extends Object> {
  number<int>(42),
  name<String>('creativecreatorormaybenot'),
  baz(true); // Note that type inference also works.

  const Bar(this.value);
  final T value;
}
```

### Mixins and interfaces

In addition to declaring members, you can also mixin mixins and implement interfaces with enhanced enums and override any missing implementations.

```dart
mixin Foo {
  int get n;
}

abstract class Bar {
  void printNumber();
}

enum Baz with Foo implements Bar {
  one(1),
  two(2);
  
  const Baz(this.n);

  @override
  final int n;

  @override
  void printNumber() => print(n);
}
```

### Multiple arguments

Finally note that even if I did not make use of it in any of the examples above, it is possible to have an arbitrary number of arguments (and an initializer list):

```dart
enum Foo {
  bar(42, description: 'The answer to life, the universe, and everything.'),
  baz(0, enabled: false, description: 'noop');

  const Foo(
    int number, {
    this.enabled = true,
    required this.description,
  }) : n = number;
  final int n;
  final bool enabled;
  final String description;
}
```

Comment: What is a use case for generics? And what about mixins and interfaces? I guess my mind is stuck on the old fashioned enums.

Comment: OK, I can think of use cases for mixins and interfaces, but I really can't think of a serious use case for generics.

Comment: @Suragch I would assume all of these features were added for completeness sake without a deeper motivation. Though there are always use cases for generics. Say you want to add a method to the class that behaves differently based on the generic type.

Comment: Generics would be a way to accomplish something similar to Kotlin Sealed Classes I supposed.

Comment: You can use enum generics when you want to store data in enums and want to restrict what kind of data it is, same with generic classes. For example, say you wanted an exhaustive way to specify static configuration data for a sublist of pages: https://dartpad.dev/?id=200aded3bd14a91a93ec0a5e9c92ae52 (I'm not sure I would do this specific example in practice, but I could definitely see this concept being very useful in organizing page/routing declarations.)

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot, Thanks, nice summary. Still don't know how I can do a very basic thing, namely if I have an enhanced enum of custom int values, how can I create an enum variable if I know the int value? E.g. `Foo myvar = Foo(2)`, but this does not work.

Answer (score 401):

Starting with Dart 2.6 you can define extensions on classes (Enums included).

```
enum Cat {
  black,
  white
}

extension CatExtension on Cat {

  String get name {
    switch (this) {
      case Cat.black:
        return 'Mr Black Cat';
      case Cat.white:
        return 'Ms White Cat';
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }

  void talk() {
    print('meow');
  }
}
```

Example:

```
Cat cat = Cat.black;
String catName = cat.name;
cat.talk();
```

Here's one more live example (uses a constant map instead of a switch):
https://dartpad.dartlang.org/c4001d907d6a420cafb2bc2c2507f72c

Comment: Is it possible to extend enum values? like adding one more value or removing one?

Comment: @PhaniRithvij Yes, it's possible as I showed in the example above. You also have different options to implement this. Check out the dartpad link as well.

Comment: No, I mean to change the entries in the original enum. eg. `enum X{a, b};` after defining an extension on it will have 3 entries. i.e. `enum X{a, b, c}` something like `extension MyEnum on X{   /*  modify the values here */  }`

Comment: I don't think it's possible. I've looked at the extensions feature [specification](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/master/accepted/2.6/static-extension-members/feature-specification.md#dart-static-extension-methods-design).

Comment: @PhaniRithvij You can't do that. The whole purpose of the enum is to have those static constants. Use a normal class instead.

Comment: Is it possible to add a static method like fromString() to enum extension ?

Comment: @AdamStyrc No it's not possible right now. See https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/41

Comment: this is called verbosity.

Comment: I was not able to use enum extension with switch cases as it was saying 'case expressions must be constant'.

Answer (score 39):

Dart enums are used only for the simplest cases. If you need more powerful or more flexible enums, use classes with static const fields like shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/15854550/217408

This way you can add whatever you need.

Comment: With enums combined to a `switch` there's a warning if you don't cover all the enum values. Do you know if there's a way to achieve this behavior with custom classes? For maintainability purposes

Comment: There is no way to get this with custom classes. See also https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/34847

Answer (score 34):

Nope. In Dart, enums can only contain the enumerated items:

```
enum Color {
  red,
  green,
  blue
}
```

However, each item in the enum automatically has an index number associated with it:

```
print(Color.red.index);    // 0
print(Color.green.index);  // 1
```

You can get the values by their index numbers:

```
print(Color.values[0] == Color.red);  // True
```

See: https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#enums

Comment: `MyEnum.values` is all what I've ever wanted. This coupled with extension methods is enough for me.

Answer (score 30):

It may not be "Effective Dart" , I add a static method inside a Helper class ( there is no companion object in Dart) .

In your `color.dart` file

```
enum Color {
  red,
  green,
  blue
}

class ColorHelper{

  static String getValue(Color color){
    switch(color){
      case Color.red: 
        return "Red";
      case Color.green: 
        return "Green";
      case Color.blue: 
        return "Blue";  
      default:
        return "";
    }
  }

}
```

Since the method is in the same file as the enum, one import is enough

```
import 'package:.../color.dart';

...
String colorValue = ColorHelper.getValue(Color.red);
```

Answer (score 12):

I did this (inspired form the accepted answer by @vovahost)

```dart
enum CodeVerifyFlow {
  SignUp, Recovery, Settings
}

extension CatExtension on CodeVerifyFlow {
  String get name {
    return ["sign_up", "recovery", "settings"][index];
  }
}

// use it like
CodeVerifyFlow.SignUp.name
```

thank me later!

Answer (score 9):

extension is good, but it cannot add static methods. If you want to do something like MyType.parse(string), consider using a class with static const fields instead (as Günter Zöchbauer suggested before).

Here is an example

```
class PaymentMethod {
  final String string;
  const PaymentMethod._(this.string);

  static const online = PaymentMethod._('online');
  static const transfer = PaymentMethod._('transfer');
  static const cash = PaymentMethod._('cash');

  static const values = [online, transfer, cash];

  static PaymentMethod parse(String value) {
    switch (value) {
      case 'online':
        return PaymentMethod.online;
        break;
      case 'transfer':
        return PaymentMethod.transfer;
        break;
      case 'cash':
        return PaymentMethod.cash;
      default:
        print('got error, invalid payment type $value');
        return null;
    }
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'PaymentMethod.$string';
  }
}
```

I found this much handier than using a helper function.

```
final method = PaymentMethod.parse('online');
assert(method == PaymentMethod.online);
```

Comment: Indeed, the inability to create some sort of factory based on the values makes the extensions a bit awkward. You can create a static `parse` method on the extension, but then it can only be called with `ExtensionName.parse()`, which is not discoverable for end-users.

I'll update my answer to point this out

Comment: To improve on this solution further, you could store the strings in a `const Map<String, PaymentMethod>`, and in parse just return the value for that key, and either return null or throw an error.

have a look here: https://gist.github.com/boukeversteegh/f67e58f500f3c0c7126640bb43e11197

Answer (score 8):

There's an upcoming feature in Dart known as enhanced enums, and it allows for enum declarations with many of the features known from classes. For example:

```dart
enum Blah {
  one(1), two(2);
  final num value;
  const Blah(this.value);
}
```

The feature is not yet released (and note that several things are not yet working), but experiments with it can be performed with a suitably fresh version of the tools by passing `--enable-experiment=enhanced-enums`.

The outcome is that `Blah` is an enum declaration with two values `Blah.one` and `Blah.two`, and we have `Blah.one.value == 1` and `Blah.two.value == 2`. The current bleeding edge handles this example in the common front end (so `dart` and `dart2js` will handle it), but it is not yet handled by the analyzer.

Comment: Once this feature hits mainstream Dart, I'll mark this answer as the accepted one. However, I'm not doing Dart development or following Dart news, so unless someone notifies me here, there may be a substantial lag time between the two.

Comment: Current status: The enhanced enums feature is enabled by default in version 2.17.0-266.5.beta, cf. https://dart.dev/get-dart/archive.

Comment: Thanks for the update Erik. Unfortunately I've already accepted https://stackoverflow.com/a/71412047/2525150 as it noted when it would hit mainstream and provided a bit more detail on how these can be used.

Answer (score 5):

As an improvement on the other suggestions of using Extensions, you can define your assigned values in a list or map, and the extension will be concise.

```dart
enum Numbers {
  one,
  two,
  three,
}

// Numbers.one.value == 1
// Numbers.two.value == 2
// Numbers.three.value == 3
```

example with list

```dart
extension NumbersExtensionList on Numbers {
  static const values = [1, 2, 3];
  int get value => values[this.index];
}
```

example with map

```dart
extension NumbersExtensionMap on Numbers {
  static const valueMap = const {
    Numbers.one: 1,
    Numbers.two: 2,
    Numbers.three: 3,
  };
  int get value => valueMap[this];
}
```

> **Note:** This approach has the limitation that you can **not** define a *static factory method* on the Enum, e.g. `Numbers.create(1)` (as of Dart 2.9). You *can* define this method on the `NumbersExtension`, but it would need to be called like `NumbersExtension.create(1)`

Comment: I think this is the best option because the Map makes it secure for additional values. In the solutions with lists, it will always be dangerous to change/delete/add enum types and corresponding values.

Answer (score 0):

For String returns :

```
enum Routes{
  SPLASH_SCREEN,
  HOME,
  // TODO Add according to your context
}

String namedRoute(Routes route){
  final runtimeType = '${route.runtimeTypes.toString()}.';
  final output = route.toString();
  return output.replaceAll(runtimeType, "");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add extra fields and methods with my package [enum_extendable](https://pub.dev/packages/enum_extendable_generator).
It generates extensions on enum, so you can use your enum values in the similar way to instances of a regular Dart class.

For example, if you have `enum MathOperator { plus, minus }` the `symbol` and `calculate(...)` can be added to it.
So, the enum can be used in such way:

```
final n1 = 1;
final n2 = 2.0;
MathOperator.values.forEach((operator) {
  print('$n1 ${operator.symbol} $n2 = ${operator.calculate(n1, n2)}');
});
```

Usage:

1. Add dependencies to pubspec.yaml:

   `dependencies:`
     `enum_extendable_annotation:`

   `dev_dependencies:`
     `build_runner:`
     `enum_extendable_generator:`

Install these dependencies:

```
# Dart
pub get

# Flutter
flutter packages get
```

2. Add imports to your enum file:

   `import 'package:enum_extendable_annotation/enum_extendable_annotation.dart';`

   `part '<your enum file name>.enum_extendable.g.dart';`
3. Create a PODO class with fields and methods you wanted.
4. Create a map with instances of this PODO class for each enum value.
5. Annotate elements:

- the enum with `@ExtendableEnum()`;
- the PODO class - `@ExtendableEnumPodo()`;
- the map of PODO instances - `@ExtendableEnumValues()`.

6. Run code generator:

- if your package depends on Flutter:

  `flutter pub run build_runner build`
- if your package does not depend on Flutter:

  `dart pub run build_runner build`

The file with extensions should be generated.

Example of the enum file:

```
import 'package:enum_extendable_annotation/enum_extendable_annotation.dart';

part 'math_operator.enum_extendable.g.dart';

@ExtendableEnum()
enum MathOperator { plus, minus }

@ExtendableEnumPodo()
class _MathOperatorPodo {

  final String symbol;
  final num Function(num, num) calculate;

  _MathOperatorPodo(
    this.symbol,
    this.calculate,
  );

  @ExtendableEnumValues()
  static final Map<MathOperator, _MathOperatorPodo> _values = {
  MathOperator.plus: _MathOperatorPodo(
     '+',
      (n1, n2) => n1 + n2,
    ),
  MathOperator.minus: _MathOperatorPodo(
      '-',
      (n1, n2) => n1 - n2,
    ),
  };
}
```