# Override or add arguments to enum in dart/ flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to override or add arguments to enums in dart?

```
// something like this
@override
enum MyEnum {new, values}


MyEnum.add(newValue)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38908285/add-methods-or-values-to-enum-in-dart

Comment: It is a very similar case. However what i want to acomplish is to add a value to an existing enum defined by default in flutter. My bad not being clear enough.

Comment: As per I know, not possible in dart

Answer (score 0):

As of now, dart enums are not mutable structures.