# How to set associated constant values of enum members in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

The only thing I can find to set the enum value is this:
[Add methods or values to enum in dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38908285/add-methods-or-values-to-enum-in-dart)

However, I find it a bit tedious.
Is there a better way?

In `C#` I can just simply do something like this:

```
enum ErrorCode
{
    None = 0,
    Unknown = 1,
    ConnectionLost = 100,
    OutlierReading = 200
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the simple exapmle

```
enum ErrorCode {
  None,
  Unknown,
  ConnectionLost,
  OutlierReading,
}

extension ErrorCodeExtention on ErrorCode {
  static final values = {
    ErrorCode.None: 0,
    ErrorCode.Unknown: 1,
    ErrorCode.ConnectionLost: 100,
    ErrorCode.OutlierReading: 200,
  };

  int? get value => values[this];
}
```

Comment: That is slightly shorter, thanks, but I think this way is still a bit tedious.

Answer (score 0):

There's an upcoming feature in Dart known as enhanced enums, and it allows for enum declarations with many of the features known from classes. For example:

```dart
enum ErrorCode {
    None(0),
    Unknown(1),
    ConnectionLost(100),
    OutlierReading(200);
  final int value;
  const ErrorCode(this.value);
}
```

The feature is not yet released (and note that several things are not yet working), but experiments with it can be performed with a suitably fresh version of the tools by passing `--enable-experiment=enhanced-enums`.

The outcome is that `ErrorCode` is an enum declaration with four values `ErrorCode.None`, `ErrorCode.Unknown`, and so on, and we have `ErrorCode.None.value == 0` and `ErrorCode.Unknown.value == 1`, and so on. The current bleeding edge handles this example in the common front end (so `dart` and `dart2js` will handle it), but it is not yet handled by the analyzer.

Comment: unfortunately as of now the properties can not be treated as constant values

Comment: Sergio, I think you are referring to the fact that the properties of an enum is not a constant expression, for example:


```dart
enum ErrorCode {
  none(0),
  unknown(1),
  connectionLost(100),
  outlierReading(200);

  final int value;
  const ErrorCode(this.value);
}

const c1 = ErrorCode.none;
const c2 = ErrorCode.none.value; // Error, not a constant value.
```

Please check out https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/2780 for further discussions about this topic.

Comment: exactly that, thanks for sending the reference to this particular issue

Answer (score 0):

Try to use private named const constructor by using underscore instead of the name. It behaves like enum as it can't be instatntiated from outside the class.

```
class ErrorCode {
  final int code;
  const ErrorCode._(this.code);

  static const ErrorCode None = ErrorCode._(0);
  static const ErrorCode Unknown = ErrorCode._(1);
  static const ErrorCode ConnectionLost = ErrorCode._(100);
  static const ErrorCode OutlierReading = ErrorCode._(200);
}
```

then you can use it just like this:

```
var a = ErrorCode.ConnectionLost;
print(a.code);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `Dart 2.17`, you can declare enums with members like this:

```dart
enum ErrorCode {
  None(0),
  Unknown(1),
  ConnectionLost(100),
  OutlierReading(200);

  const ErrorCode(this.code);

  final int code;
}

print(ErrorCode.None.code);
print(ErrorCode.Unknown.code);
print(ErrorCode.ConnectionLost.code);
print(ErrorCode.OutlierReading.code);
```