# Flutter call dynamicaly function attribute with string

Tags: flutter, icons

Want to call Icons.album with the string "album" like Icons["album"] but it's not work's. do I need to do enum for each icon or it was a other way ?

```
List tasks = [{
    "title": "task 1",
    "description": "description 1",
    "icon": "ring_volume",
  },{
    "title": "task 2",
    "description": "description 2",
    "icon": "flag",
  },{
    "title": "task 3",
    "description": "description 3",
    "icon": "album",
  },
  ];

[...]

  Widget taskCard(Map task) {
    Text title = Text(task['title']);
    return Center(
      child: Card(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
             ListTile(
              leading: Icons(Icons.album), // HERE
              title: new Text(task['title']),
              subtitle: new Text(task['description']),
            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call the icons like these `Icons["album"]` but you can store `IconData` in the maps like this

```dart
List tasks = [{
    "title": "task 1",
    "description": "description 1",
    "icon": Icons.ring_volume,
  },{
    "title": "task 2",
    "description": "description 2",
    "icon": Icons.flag,
  },{
    "title": "task 3",
    "description": "description 3",
    "icon": Icons.album,
  },
  ];
```

then call it in your UI the like `task['icon']`

```dart
  Widget taskCard(Map task) {
    Text title = Text(task['title']);
    return Center(
      child: Card(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
             ListTile(
              leading: Icons(task['icon']), // HERE
              title: new Text(task['title']),
              subtitle: new Text(task['description']),
            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use this:

in dictionary:

```
"icon": Icons.album
```

and in widget:

```
leading: Icon(task["icon"])
```

Comment: thank's, it work's but it's hard to use widget with IconData type. I prefere storage a string

Comment: You need to make a workaround to use strings. Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44060511/4335775

Comment: well, you can put all the widget in "icon" property to use easier.
"icon": Icon(Icons.album)

leading: task["icon"]