# How to loop over an enum in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, enums

I have a Dart enum in my Flutter project like this:

```dart
enum RepeatState {
  playSongOnce,
  repeatSong,
  repeatPlaylist,
}
```

If I have some random enum state like `RepeatState.repeatSong`, how do I iterate to the next enum (without doing something like mapping them with a switch statement)?

I found the answer with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29567669/3681880), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53011471/3681880) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51190099/3681880), so I'm posting it below.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Given an enum like so,

```dart
enum MyEnum {
  horse,
  cow,
  camel,
  sheep,
  goat,
}
```

### Looping over the values of an enum

You can iterate over the values of the enum by using the `values` property:

```dart
for (var value in MyEnum.values) {
  print(value);
}

// MyEnum.horse
// MyEnum.cow
// MyEnum.camel
// MyEnum.sheep
// MyEnum.goat
```

### Converting between a value and its index

Each value has an index:

```dart
int index = MyEnum.horse.index; // 0
```

And you can convert an index back to an enum using subscript notation:

```dart
MyEnum value = MyEnum.values[0]; // MyEnum.horse
```

### Finding the next enum value

Combining these facts, you can loop over the values of an enum to find the next value like so:

```dart
MyEnum nextEnum(MyEnum value) {
  final nextIndex = (value.index + 1) % MyEnum.values.length;
  return MyEnum.values[nextIndex];
}
```

Using the modulo operator handles even when the index is at the end of the enum value list:

```dart
MyEnum nextValue = nextEnum(MyEnum.goat); // MyEnum.horse
```

Answer (score 8):

```
enum Fruites { Mango, Banana, Cherry, Avacado, Papaya }

void main() {
  Fruites.values.forEach((name) {
    print(name);
  });
}
```

Output:

```
Fruites.Mango
Fruites.Banana
Fruites.Cherry
Fruites.Avacado
Fruites.Papaya
```

Take name part only

```
print(name.toString().split('.').elementAt(1));
```

Output:

```
Mango
Banana
Cherry
Avacado
Papaya
```

Answer (score 4):

With **Flutter 3.0** enums, you could have extra functions to get all enum values or to get one by string value, for example:

```
enum RepeatState {
  playSongOnce,
  repeatSong,
  repeatPlaylist;

  static RepeatState getEnum(String name) => RepeatState.values.firstWhere((element) => element.name == name);
  static List<String> stringValues() => RepeatState.values.map((e) => e.name).toList();
}
```

In order to get the String value: `StatusEnum.purple.value`

And calling our extra functions:

```
print('${RepeatState.stringValues()}');
print('${RepeatState.getEnum('repeatSong')}');
```

Gives us:

```
I/flutter (14298): [playSongOnce, repeatSong, repeatPlaylist]
I/flutter (14298): RepeatState.repeatSong
```

More on new enums is [here](https://medium.com/@tonia.tkachuk/using-enums-like-a-pro-in-flutter-4563dde2e8a9).

Comment: How about looping over the values? For example, could you have a `RepeatState.next` getter?